# Web-based email client that works with Microsoft Exchange

Tags: web-apps, email-client, microsoft-exchange

I'm currently working abroad and the internet connection I use blocks direct access to the Microsoft Exchange server that my company uses.

Does anyone know of a web-based client that I could use with my company's existing Microsoft Exchange server?

This seems like the easiest workaround. I know Gmail allows POP3 but only the applications can be setup for Exchange server.

Comment: [Outlook Web App](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlook_Web_App)?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Outlook-Web-App needs to be hosted on the exchange server and isn't actually just a web client.  When you search for it you usually find links that are company specific.  The only generic one I could find was https://outlook.office365.com/ but it appears your organization needs affiliated with it.  I'm just looking for a strict web-client that will access an existing exchange server without having to host or create anything on my own.

Comment: If your exchange server has imap configured you could put squirrelmail up on a webserver somewhere, configured to point to the exchange server's imap

Answer (score 0):

**Not to steal anyone's thunder, but what about temporarily forwarding your email from your exchange server  to another email address that can be opened on a web based client?**

```
For web-based clients, check out "roundcube" or for more secure means "mailpile"
```

**The only problem you may have is actually configuring your gmail so it works in a way that you are able to send emails as if it was yourself answering from the exchange server.**

- 1) Go to your gmail and login in. Upon opening in the right corner, there should be a gear icon.
- 2)    Click the gear in the top right  .
- 3)    Select Settings.
- 4)    Click the Accounts and Import tab.
- 5)    Under Send mail as, click Add another email address.
- 6)    In the 'Email address' field, enter your name and alternate email address you own.
- 7)    Enter the SMTP server (e.g. smtp.domain.com), your username on that domain, and your password for that account. You may also need to adjust your port setting or SSL setting (talk to your other ISP if you need this information).
- 8)    Click Add account >>
- 9)    Open your other account and either click the link in the message Gmail sent or enter the confirmation code in the Accounts and Import section of your Gmail settings

  - If Gmail sent a verification email and you didn’t receive it, try checking your Spam or Bulk Mail folders for a message from account-verification-noreply@google.com to see if the email ended up in there.

### Additional information

Your other email provider has to provide authenticated SMTP support for you to use this option. We'll use TLS by default, or SSL if you enable it. Many email services that provide POP or IMAP support also offer authenticated SMTP support, and you can likely find your SMTP server configuration instructions alongside information about POP or IMAP. Also, this new version of custom 'From:' doesn't work with Yahoo! Mail Plus accounts just yet.
If the address you’re adding is hosted by Google (either a Google Apps account or a @gmail.com address), your original address will still be included in your email header's sender field to help prevent your mail from being marked as spam. Most email clients don't display the sender field, though some versions of Microsoft Outlook may display "From yourusername@gmail.com on behalf of customaddress@mydomain.com."##

> This information is from Gmail Help "I'm a Gmail or Google Apps user sending from an external address."*

### Solution for Email Forwarding

> I do not have enough rep to post more than two links/pictures, but you should
>   find this if you google "Configure email forwarding for a mailbox -
>   TechNet - Microsoft"

[image]

[image: Configure email forwarding for a mailbox]

---

Hope this helps!

The issue that I cannot account for is whether or not the isp ,in the country you are staying in, blocks certain email client's ip addresses or website.